# how to pass parameter value to service function in angularjs controller?

Tags: angularjs

i have angularjs project where on homepage i want to show several selected articles (objects) from my mongodb database. in the database, i have two collections -- one is  'articles' with few hundred individual articles (objects) and other is 'homepage' where i have only ten objects with just 'articleID' key which contains the id of the object from the first collection. my problem is that when i hardcode articleID in controller all works fine but when i first fetch articleID from 'homepage' collection and then pass that value to function 'getArticle01' which fetch selected object from the first collection it does not work. please, can anyone let me know what i'm doing wrong?

here is my code:

```js
var articleId01 = '58da9967a8bccd763c48bdc0'; // if i hardcode article id here, all works fine
HomepageService
  .findAllHomepages() // returns array with 10 objects from my api
  .then(function(homepages) {
    var articleId01 = homepages.data[0].articleID;
    console.log(articleId01); // so far, all is ok, console logs value: '58da9967a8bccd763c48bdc0'
  }, function(error) {
      console.log('error', error);
  })
  .then(function(){
    function getArticle01() {
      HomepageService
        .findHomepageById(articleId01) // unfortunately, value is not passed here
        // .findHomepageById('58da9967a8bccd763c48bdc1') // if value is hardcoded, all is ok
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.data);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log('error', error); // here is error from console: Object {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: "", headers: function}
        });
    }

    getArticle01();

  });
```

Comment: You redefine articleId01 here: var articleId01 = homepages.data[0].articleID; so when you need it in another function it doesn't exists. Maybe use a scope variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `var articleId01` is in the scope of the first `then()` function. It is not visible inside the second `then()`.
Your can get it if you return `articleId01` at the end of your first `then()` and use it as a parameter in your second `then()`:

```js
HomepageService
  .findAllHomepages() // returns array with 10 objects from my api
  .then(function(homepages) {
    var articleId01 = homepages.data[0].articleID; 
    //Return your id
    return articleId01;
  }, function(error) {
      console.log('error', error);
  })
  //Get your id
  .then(function(articleId){
    function getArticle01() {
      HomepageService
      //Use the id
        .findHomepageById(articleId) 
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.data);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log('error', error); 
        });
    }

    getArticle01();

  });
```

Comment: thank you very much, but it didn't work. 'var articleId01' is still not visible inside second .then scope. I have already tried same approach but it didn't work and I really can't figure out why. nevertheless, thank you very much for suggestion...

Comment: Maybe I misundestand you, but do you still want to get 'var articleId01' in the second .then()? In my example this variable is passed as 'articleId' into the second .then() and so it's visible. :) see:  '.findHomepageById(articleId)'

Comment: hi, sorry for late reply but you were absolutely and 100% right. it was another error in my code that 'caused my app to crash and i didn't notice it as i have written this code snippet right here in the stackowerflow editor and not copied from my javascript file -- so code here was correct and same code in my app had additional errors... :-(  again, thank you so, so much for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, and it works really nice to me is to build a getter/setter for this id inside your service.

On your service:

```
return {
    setId: setId,
    getId: getId,
...}

    function setId(str) {
        idStr = str;
    }
    function getId() {
        return idStr;
    }
```

Then you may set it before calling your service:

```
HomepageService.setId('your_id');
```

And inside your service you can call it like:

```
var myId = getId(); // and use it
```

Its really usefull to me and keeps my code pretty clean. I hope it helps.
You can do a lot with them, some more info here:

[Getters- Setters](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/12/es5-getters-setters/)